# Using SQLAlchemy Connection Pooling Queues with Python multiprocessing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, connection-pooling

The SQLAlchemy documentation "[How do I use engines / connections / sessions with Python multiprocessing, or os.fork()?](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/faq/connections.html#how-do-i-use-engines-connections-sessions-with-python-multiprocessing-or-os-fork)" does not consider using connection pooling queues with multiprocessing.

The example given does not specify a Queue using a `poolclass` kwarg, therefore the default `None` queue is used. I have found when using queues that you need to **also** apply the `add_engine_pidguard` function to the imported queue class  **prior** to creating the engine or else the connections hang.

When using the stock example, some connections are logged as being checked out, but your application will hang eventually. This can be easily verified as you will see many process ids for your application in your process table when using the `ps aux | grep application_name` command that are not logged.

The resulting working code looks like this when using the `QueuePool` class.

**Note:** the add_engine_pidguard function is identical to the documentation:

```
import os
import warnings

from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy import exc
from sqlalchemy.pool import QueuePool

add_engine_pidguard(QueuePool)
engine = create_engine("...", poolclass=QueuePool)
add_engine_pidguard(engine)

def add_engine_pidguard(engine):
    """Add multiprocessing guards.

    Forces a connection to be reconnected if it is detected
    as having been shared to a sub-process.

    """

    @event.listens_for(engine, "connect")
    def connect(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
        connection_record.info['pid'] = os.getpid()

    @event.listens_for(engine, "checkout")
    def checkout(dbapi_connection, connection_record, connection_proxy):
        pid = os.getpid()
        if connection_record.info['pid'] != pid:
            # substitute log.debug() or similar here as desired
            warnings.warn(
                "Parent process %(orig)s forked (%(newproc)s) with an open "
                "database connection, "
                "which is being discarded and recreated." %
                {"newproc": pid, "orig": connection_record.info['pid']})
            connection_record.connection = connection_proxy.connection = None
            raise exc.DisconnectionError(
                "Connection record belongs to pid %s, "
                "attempting to check out in pid %s" %
                (connection_record.info['pid'], pid)
            )
```

---

**Versions (Multiple)**

- OS: CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
- Python: 3.6.8
- SQLAlchemy: 1.3.15
- Database: MariaDB-Galera-server-10.0.38-1
- DBAPI: pymysql 0.9.3

---

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Python: 3.8.2
- SQLAlchemy: 1.3.16
- Database: mariadb-server-10.3 (1:10.3.22-1ubuntu1)
- DBAPI: pymysql 0.9.3

---

I need others to verify whether this observation is correct and whether my solution is officially recommended. I will update the SQLAlchemy documentation if this is so.